# access 2016 System resource exceeded

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am try to migrate from access 2003 to 2016 When I am importing my objects everything is fine. Only,on the process of importing 3 tables, I am getting this error.

> System resource exceeded

They are big tables too.
There is no hotfix for access 2016, Total table quantity around 100 tables
If you help me I really appreciate

Comment: what is the error you are getting it is not clear...

Comment: System resource exceeded

Comment: did you looked at this https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2726928 ?

Comment: Yes but this is for ms access 2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since currently there is no hot fix for 2016 version you have to merge either to 2010 or 2013. Then you can try merging to 2016.

Please check this link:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/aedecca8-aa7d-417f-9f03-6e63e36f0c5d/access-2016-system-resources-exceeded?forum=Office2016setupdeploy&prof=required

Answer (score 3):

Found solution here: 
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/ms-access-2016-system-resource-exceeded/df80f64a-f233-467e-89df-f05a8d58bc77

In short:
 task manager/processes tab, find `msaccess`, right click and select set affinity.... option.  I had 6 CPUs ticked (0 to 5).  I un-ticked them all and just ticked the 0 CPU.

Comment: Solution also works for general Access 2016 use. Thanks +1

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will help you, but I've managed to resolve this error by wrapping fields referenced in the WHERE clause with `Nz` e.g.

instead of

```
WHERE ReportDate = Date
```

use

```
WHERE Nz(ReportDate,ReportDate) = Date
```

It's strange but it seems to work for me, I've found the issue is often related to indexed fields, so I always add it to those fields first